# Get "DC" value from result of Get-ADDomain?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Now I just want to get two value `DC` from the result of `Get-ADDomain` command and I assign it to two different variables in Powershell.

Example

```
$dc1=mydomain
$dc2=com
```

How can I do it with Powershell?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attribute DNSRoot an split it at the dot like this:

```
$Domain = Get-ADDomain 
$dc1 = $Domain.DNSRoot.split('.')[0]
$dc2 = $Domain.DNSRoot.split('.')[1]
```

Comment: Both of you and TobyU given me the correct answer which what I expect. But you anwser soon so I have no way to vote for you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `split` can do this:

```
$dn = (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName
$list = $dn -split 'dc='
$dc1 = $list[($list.Length -2)] -replace ',',''
$dc2 = $list[($list.Length -1)]
```

Comment: Thanks TobyU. Your way also right! Thank you so much!

Comment: @olaf's solution is the neater one, I have to admit.